# Understanding the different type of SOLR commits

Tags: solr, document, solrcloud

I want to clarify my understanding about different type of Solr commits. Please correct me if I am wrong.

- `commits`: all type of commits including **SOFT** and **HARD** commits.
- `autoCommit`: does a **HARD** commit to the disk and make sure all the autoSoftCommit commits are written to disk and commits any other pending documents.
- `autoSoftCommit` - does a **SOFT** commit . After a autoSoftCommit, if the the SOLR server goes down, the autoSoftCommit documents will be lost.
- `autocommit maxTime`: Maximum time between two autocommits execution (in my case it is set as **15000s**)
- `soft autocommit maxTime`:Maximum documents ‘adds’ between two **SOFT** auto-commits. (in my case it is set as **180000s**)

> So, if we set commit=true parameter to any solr api call with some
>   document data, then it does HARD commit to current document also to
>   the pending documents. doc will updated on the disk within
>   (15000ms=15secs)
>
> So, if we set commit=false parameter to any solr api call with some
>   document data, then it does SOFT commit to current document also to
>   the pending documents. doc will updated on the disk within
>   (180000ms=3mins)

Solr Stats url : https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Performance+Statistics+Reference

[image]

> Is it possible to give an example for commit, autoCommit and
>   softCommit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend this Old but Gold article[1] and this recent mail thread[2].
Also your distinction in how you can trigger Hard and Soft commit is not quite right [3]

[1] https://lucidworks.com/2013/08/23/understanding-transaction-logs-softcommit-and-commit-in-sorlcloud/

[2] http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/High-disk-write-usage-td4344356.html#a4345233

[3] https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/UpdateHandlers+in+SolrConfig#UpdateHandlersinSolrConfig-commitandsoftCommit

Comment: many many thanks for your reference link related to solr commits :). Actually, Now I need to know from you what actually happens when we set `commit=true` or `commit=false` with url ? is it hard commit or soft commit ?  what is the default value of `commit` param?

Comment: Have you read [3] ?
If you set commit=true you ask for an Hard Commit.
If you don't set it ( or you set it false) you don't ask for a commit at all.